# Wrong parent HWND in modal dialog

Tags: c++, windows, window, atl

Why do i get desktop as a parent HWND for my modal dialog here?

```
class CSaveProfileAsDlg:
 public CSimpleDialog<IDD_DLG_RESOURCE>
{
  ....
  LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT,  WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&)
  {
    ...
    HWND parent = GetParent(); // or GetAncestor(m_hWnd, GA_PARENT);
    assert(parent != GetDesktopWindow()); // not ok
    ...
  }
 ....
}


//somewhere in code
//m_hWnd is some valid HWND
assert(m_hWnd != GetDesktopWindow()); //ok
CSaveProfileAsDlg dlg;
dlg.DoModal(m_hWnd /*as a parent wnd*/);
```

I can "solve" it by passing corret HWND in `CSaveProfileAsDlg` ctor, but i'd like to have correct solution.

Thank you!

Comment: you not try `assert(parent != 0);` ?

Comment: I do in production code, just removed it in this example. ```parent``` i get is valid HWND.

Comment: you sure that it != 0 ?

Comment: really this `assert(parent != GetDesktopWindow()); ` absolute senseless , when compare with 0 have sense

Comment: The problem is i get desktop as a parent window, not window i pass in DoModal. This code is just for demonstration of a problem.

Comment: What is the `CSimpleDialog`-Class? `CDialog::DoModal()` doesn't expect any parameter. Correct solution is that you pass in ctor.

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem in first place? It rather looks as behavior by design.

Comment: @YusufRamazanKaragöz ```CSimpleDialog``` is an ATL class, its method ```DoModal``` accepts parent HWND.

Comment: `m_hWnd` argument in `DoModal` call might be a valid window but still not suitable as a parent, in which case the dialog box is still shown but effective parent is different.

Comment: @RomanR. that's interesting, never heard about it. Could you tell more or provide certain links for reading, please? How come ```m_hWnd``` can be not suitable as a parent window?

Comment: For example, if you pass a child window handle, effective owner would be a parent of the argument window. That is, effective parent does not have to be an exact match. You don't actually need to care what is the parent window exactly. If you want to pass an argument to connect caller and window implementation (handlers), you should rather pass an `LPARAM` value you retrieve in `WM_INITDIALOG` handler from message parameters. Such parameter may be casted `HWND` and it will be passed accurately.

Comment: @RomanR. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is very confusing but I think I found the problem. `DoModal` internally calls `::DialogBox()`, one parameter of which takes a `HWND` named `hWndParent`. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452(v=vs.85).aspx):

> *hWndParent* [in, optional]
> Type: **HWND**
> A handle to the window that owns the dialog box.

The keyword here is the word "owns". The section about [owned windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features?redirectedfrom=MSDN#owned-windows) confirms this:

> Dialog boxes and message boxes are owned windows by default. An application specifies the owner window when calling a function that creates a dialog box or message box.

So we actually talk about the owner window instead of its parent. This makes sense as the dialog is a free floating window and not part of a window hierarchy as "parenthood" would imply.

You can get the owning window by using:

```
HWND parent = ::GetWindow(m_hWnd, GW_OWNER);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar issue. I was wondering why GetParent() return always a different CWnd*.

The right solution is simple, just pass the desired `pWnd` to the dlg Constructor.
It will be stored in the CDialog member variable `m_pParentWnd`.
Then you can always get the passed pWnd with this member variable in your Dialog.

```
//somewhere in code
//pWnd some valid CWnd pointer

CSaveProfileAsDlg dlg (pWnd);  // relevant!
dlg.DoModal();
```

.

```
class CSaveProfileAsDlg:
 public CSimpleDialog<IDD_DLG_RESOURCE>
{
  ....
  LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT,  WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&)
  {
    ...
    CWnd* _pWnd = GetParent();  // not ok, returns probably CMainFrame or similiar
    CWnd* pWnd = m_pParentWnd;  // your parent Wnd
    ...
  }
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got two versions of the same application and one of them disables all parent popup windows as it should when DoModal is called. Second version disables only top-level CMainFrame and real parent is stay enabled so I can call modal dialog twice and more.

This happen in CWnd::GetSafeOwner_, line :
hWnd = ::GetLastActivePopup(hWnd);

Firsts version return real parent while second version return CMainFrame.
I've spent one day and could not find the cause of such behaviour. However I've found workaround:

When DoModal is called it Disable CMainFrame so I can disable it's children also:

```
afx_msg void OnEnable(BOOL bEnable);

ON_WM_ENABLE()

void CMainFrame::OnEnable(BOOL bEnable)
{
    std::for_each(m_bars.begin(), m_bars.end(), 
        [=](const std::pair<EBar, BaseBar*>& bar)
    { 
        bar.second->EnableWindow(bEnable);
    });
}
```